# Catch closing event of a part (Eclipse e4 RCP)

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I'm currently working on a eclipse e4 RCP application and I have a part that serves as a job manager where the user can see all active jobs and their progresses, like one in eclipse. The problem is now that the user can open the progress part by double clicking in the toolbar and he should also be able to close the progress part whenever he wants, but instead of disposing the part I want to just make it invisible.
I thought at first this shouldn't be a problem because I can set the part to be not visible, but the problem is how to catch the closing event and process it by my way. Is there any event, interfaces or listeners I can implement to catch the closing event and prevent the part from getting disposed?

Comment: Are you asking about an e4 application (using the Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility mode RCP?

Comment: Yes I'm asking about an e4 application using the Application.e4xmi ...

Comment: `EPartService.addPartListener` will tell you about the close, but I don't know of anyway to stop the close happening.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a CustomSaveHandler and replace the Default Eclipse Save Handler with a Processor. In that SaveHandler you can control if the Part shoud get closed or not. So you could do not close it and make it invisible.

ExampleCode:

```
public class ReplaceSaveHandlerProcessor {
@Named("your.id.to.window")
@Inject
MWindow window;

@Inject
IEventBroker eventBroker;

@Execute
void installIntoContext() {
    eventBroker.subscribe(UIEvents.Context.TOPIC_CONTEXT, new EventHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
            if (UIEvents.isSET(event)) {
                if (window.equals(event.getProperty("ChangedElement")) && (window.getContext() != null)) {

                    window.getContext().runAndTrack(new RunAndTrack() {

                        private final ISaveHandler saveHandler = new CustomSaveHandler();

                        @Override
                        public boolean changed(final IEclipseContext context) {
                            Object getSaveHandlerValue = context.get(ISaveHandler.class);


                            if (!saveHandler.equals(getSaveHandlerValue)) { // prevents endless loop
                                ContextInjectionFactory.inject(saveHandler, window.getContext());
                                context.set(ISaveHandler.class, saveHandler);
                            }


                            return true; // ture keeps tracking and the saveHandler as the only opportunity
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
        }

    });
}
}
```

You have to define a Extention for ExtentionPoint org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model
With Your ReplaceSaveHandlerProcessor. (You have to declare the window id as "element" in this extention. (Added Screenshot: [image])

The CustomSaveHandler have to implement the ISaveHandler interface. In its Methods ypu can say if the Part should realy be closed.

```
public class CustomSaveHandler implements ISaveHandler {

@Override
public boolean save(MPart dirtyPart, boolean confirm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean saveParts(Collection<MPart> dirtyParts, boolean confirm) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public Save promptToSave(MPart dirtyPart) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Save[] promptToSave(Collection<MPart> dirtyParts) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}